# Index/Match to return all rows with criteria - EXCEL

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, array-formulas

How would I set up a sheet that extracts data from a table with selected rows based off of the values from a column. In this example, I have 5 types of Chips with respective information for each. I attempted to use Filter( ) but it did not appear as an option in my version of Excel.

I have a column simply listing Food Items, "Chip 1","Chip3","Chip4". I would like to have the second table show information for only Chips 1,3,4 on another sheet.

Thanks!

EDIT
I went searching for a solution. Lookup value is in table 'Criteria' row J15 and would match one of the values in 'Data' Column A, the table where rows to be extracted from. I still get an error where Excel thinks I am mistakenly trying to type a formula. I've been trying to work on this for hours, thanks for all the help thus far.

Link for reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/8etavq/return_all_rows_that_match_a_certain_criteria_on/dxxyyta/

=INDEX('Data'!A1:A124,SMALL(IF('Data'!$A$5:$A$124='Criteria'!$J$15,ROW('Data'$A$5:$A$124)-ROW(INDEX('Data'$A$5:$A$124,1,1))+1),row()-2))

| Food Item |
| --- |
| Chip 1 |
| Chip 3 |
| Chip 4 |

Original table

| Food Item | Caloric Count | Percentage of Protein | Percentage of Fat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chip 1 | 111 | 1% | 2% |
| Chip 2 | 500 | 3% | 2.5% |
| Chip 3 | 40 | .4% | .5% |
| Chip 4 | 50 | .5% | .5% |
| Chip 5 | 372 | 3% | 5% |

Table 2

| Food Item | Caloric Count | Percentage of Protein | Percentage of Fat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chip 1 | 111 | 1% | 2% |
| Chip 3 | 40 | .4% | .5% |
| Chip 4 | 50 | .5% | .5% |

Comment: How would you filter to table 3? What's the rule?

Comment: Use the Advanced Filter with the option to copy the results to another location. Since you want to copy to another worksheet, initiate the process (selecting Advanced Filter) **after** selecting the eventual Destination worksheet.

Comment: Hi, sorry the criteria table I made wasn't showing up correctly. I wanted to create a column of just the chips I wanted? And see if this is possible alone.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I looked up how to use the Advanced filter but it seemed to be not pulling all the columns I needed or correctly. I highlighted the main table as the listed table, criteria table as the column of desired foods, and highlighted the destination.

Comment: I just tried it with your data as posted and it worked fine here. But since I cannot see your screen, it's tough to tell what the issue is on your end.

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld, I've seen some video online and get the general idea. Is there a key part to making sure I highlight certain cells correctly. Are you supposed to include the header columns?

Comment: Yes, you need to include the header row for both the data table and the criteria.  As well as all the data

Comment: @RonRosenfeld When I highlight my current data set I get this message. I decided to highlight the original data first and then advanced filter.  Microsoft Excel cannot determine which row in your list or selection contains columns labels, which are required for this command.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I think I know why I am getting this error. In my actual table, the column headers have more detailed headers where its a combination of 2 rows and merged cells as well, so the system has trouble lining things uo? I was hoping to pre code the header in and have the data just go under place holders? Is this possible in any way while using the filter?

Comment: From your given sample data data to post, I think `INDEX/MATCH` should work if food item data is give to table 3.

Comment: Merged cells are a big problem. And I believe column headers need to be a single cell to use Advanced Filter. I suggest change your data table, or develop a VBA or Power Query solution.

Comment: @Harun24HR I may need to explore that. In all the examples I've seen there are multiple conditions instead of just one like what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Harun24HR Could you see if the updates I've added will help?